# Generating confusion matrix with HResults HTK Tool for handwriting recognition ICFHR’s example

Tags: htk

I am studying how HTK Tools works with handwriting recognition. Following the [ICFHR–2010 TUTORIAL](https://www.prhlt.upv.es/tutorials/icfhr2010/Exp-Guide.pdf) I run examples for "Spanish-Numbers" corpus and received the resulting HMMs (files stored in folder hmm and listed in `HMMsList`), and `res32.mlf` with results of recognition received with `HVite`. Also I have master label file SamplesRef.mlf.
And now I want to see recognition results statistics, i.e. studying `HResults` tool.

When I run `HResults` as

```
 HResults -I SamplesRef.mlf HMMsList res32.mlf
```

I see

```
====================== HTK Results Analysis =======================
  Date: Tue Mar 31 15:21:11 2015
  Ref : SamplesRef.mlf
  Rec : res32.mlf
------------------------ Overall Results --------------------------
 SENT: %Correct=0.00 [H=0, S=2, N=2]
 WORD: %Corr=77.78, Acc=77.78 [H=7, D=0, S=2, I=0, N=9]
===================================================================
```

But if I add option `-p` in order to have confusion matrix I see the following error message:

```
~/icfhr$ HResults -p -I SamplesRef.mlf HMMsList res32.mlf
 ERROR [+3331]  Index: Label millones not in list[0 of 19]
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HResults
```

I understand that message means that there is no HMM with name "millones" and I found that in my `res32.mlf` samples looks like:

```
"’*’/210341.rec"
mil
seiscientos
cincuenta
y
siete
millones
.
```

If I change `res32.mlf` with text editor to `res33.mlf` with content like:

```
"’*’/210341.rec"
m
i
l
s
e
i
s
c
i
```

... and so on.

And use `samples.mlf` (instead of `SamplesRef.mlf`) which inside looks like:

```
"*/210341.lab"
m
i
l
@
q
u
i
n
i
e
n
t
o
s
@
c
```

... and so on.

I have the desired result:

```
~/icfhr$ HResults -p -I samples.mlf HMMsList res33.mlf
====================== HTK Results Analysis =======================
  Date: Tue Mar 31 15:35:42 2015
  Ref : samples.mlf
  Rec : res33.mlf
------------------------ Overall Results --------------------------
SENT: %Correct=0.00 [H=0, S=2, N=2]
WORD: %Corr=79.63, Acc=77.78 [H=43, D=5, S=6, I=1, N=54]
------------------------ Confusion Matrix -------------------------
       a   c   d   e   i   l   m   n   o   s   t   u   v   y  Del [ %c / %e]
   @   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    5 [ 0.0/3.7]
   a   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
   c   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
   d   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
   e   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
   i   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
   l   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
   m   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
   n   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   6   0   0   0   0   0   0    0 [85.7/1.9]
   o   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0    0
   q   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0    0 [ 0.0/1.9]
   s   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0    0
   t   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0    0
   u   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0    0 [50.0/1.9]
   v   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0    0
   y   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1    0 [50.0/1.9]
Ins    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
===================================================================
```

**So, the main question is:**

What is the simplest way (without text editor) to make mlf-files adapted for making confusion matrix?

(I suppose I miss some option of some HTK tool… but which tool and which option?)

Any useful ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the -p option, you need to provide the labels list of the classes not your HMMs, (i.e. if you're trying to recognize the words Yes, No, Never) then your "HMMsList" file should be written as:

```
Yes
No
Never
```

Regardless of the HMMs that actually constitutes the words. 
Your "HMMsList" file should be "LabelsList"